# Renaming computer via Batch script

Tags: batch-file

I am attempting to create a script that will import a CVS and then rename the computer for me. I am pretty new to creating scripts, so I am open to any corrections or recommendations. Below is the script I have so far.

```
for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=," %%o in ("C:\path\computers.csv") do (
    echo netdom renamecomputer %%o /newname %%n
)
```

Comment: Once you specified that the the loop variable is `%%o`, the next token should be `%%p` (if there were more, they would be `%%q`, `%%r`, etc).  Using `%%n` doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using WMIC with the csv file from a Command Prompt/Batch file:

```dos
@For /F "UseBackQ Tokens=1-2 Delims=," %%A In ("C:\path\computers.csv") Do @WMIC /Node:"%%~A" ComputerSystem Call Rename Name="%%~B"
```

Note: The Command Prompt uses a single **`%`** instead of two **`%%`**.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `wmic` command to do it:

```
wmic computersystem where "name='%computername%'" call rename name=myNewName
```

Comment: Of course you would need Administrator privileges to succesfully rename the computer and after that a reboot is required.

Comment: If I would use wmic command instead of the netdom. Would I still use the for /f for the script to actually change the computers in the cvs that need to be changed?